# How to hook into a function offered by a plugin?

Tags: functions

I got a plugin (kind of sign up form), that offers developers some actions/hooks to add their own stuff. Inside the plugin the function is called like this:

```
// Allow devs to hook in
do_action( 'after_record_action', $result, $data, $format );
```

I guess that `$data` is an array storing the form data. After a visitor uses the signup form I want to send a mail containing `$data` using [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)

How can I execute the following script using `after_record_action`? Do I need to add this inside my `functions.php`?

```
// get data from $data[] array
$data['email'] = $email;
$data['key'] = $key;

// use $data to create a personalized mail
$to = $email;
$subject = "Wordpress Test";
$content = "Hi, this us your key:" . $key . "Enjoy using it!";

// send mail using wp_mail
$status = wp_mail($to, $subject, $content);
```

I appreciate any help in combining these, as I am not too experienced using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) I am able to add a function to the plugin.

```
// add action to after_record_action    
add_action('after_record_action', 'marian_rick_custom_action', 10, 3);

// add function
function marian_rick_custom_action ($result, $data, $format){
    // get data from $data[] array
    $email = $data['email'];
    $key = $data['key'];

    // use $data to create a personalized mail
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Wordpress Test";
    $content = "Hi, this us your key:" . $key . "Enjoy using it!";

    // send mail using wp_mail
    $status = wp_mail($to, $subject, $content);
}
```

[As stated here by Tarun Mahashwari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190400/how-to-hook-inside-a-function-in-wordpress/39190581#39190581)

Comment: Please don't forget to accept this as an answer after two days if it solved your original question.

Comment: I indented the code correctly, but you should explain how it answers the question, there's a great opportunity to introduce the `add_action` function and how hooks work, instead you've given copy-pasta which helps nobody else and gives no further understanding